# Помогите с реляционным ActivaRecord в Yii

Tags: activerecord, yii

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться с реляционными моделями. Я не могу понять как мне реализовать такую вещь:

У меня есть 2 таблицы

1) tb_users 
    (поля: id, username, password, email)

2) tb_partner
    (поля: id, id_user, amount)

И чтобы я мог связать поля id(tb_users) и id_user(tb_partner), и я мог получить значение поля amount конкретного пользоватя одним запросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [Gii](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.gii) для генерации моделей. Если в БД используются типы таблиц с внешними ключами и эти ключи правильно настроены, Gii самостоятельно сгенерирует связи между таблицами в классах. Должно получиться что-то вроде такого (имена таблиц записал с учетом того, что префикс tb_ задан в конфиге приложения):

```
class Users extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
         return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function relations()
    {
         return array(
              'partner' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Partner', 'id_user')
         );
    }
}

class Partner extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
         return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function relations()
    {
         return array(
              'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'id_user')
         );
    }
}
```

Если я правильно понял, то связь между таблицами один к одному, поэтому использовал HAS_ONE.

Пользоваться связями можно по-разному, например, используя ленивую загрузку:

```
$user = Users::model()->findByPk(1);
$value = $user->partner->value; // будет выполнен дополнительный запрос к таблице tb_partner
```

или со сложным запросом:

```
$user = Users::model()->width('partner')->findByPk(1);
$value = $user->partner->value; // запрос выполняться не будет
```

Более подробно можно почитать в [официальной документации](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr), там все довольно подробно расписано, с примерами.